# An error occured 'maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height' when I encode my video

Tags: ffmpeg

I always use this source code when I encode my videos. they are almost 1920x1080 videos.
but An error occured when I tried to encode a 7680x3840 video.

```
    ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
    configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
    libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
    libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
    libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
    libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
    libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
    libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
    libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
    libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
    [avisynth @ 03af8040] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
    Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
    Input #0, avisynth, from 'a.mp4.avs':
    Duration: 00:00:01.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 7680x3840, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_f32le, 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 3072 kb/s
    [libx264 @ 054c5c20] VBV maxrate specified, but no bufsize, ignored
    [libx264 @ 054c5c20] frame MB size (480x240) > level limit (8192)
    [libx264 @ 054c5c20] DPB size (4 frames, 460800 mbs) > level limit (0 frames, 32768 mbs)
    [libx264 @ 054c5c20] MB rate (6912000) > level limit (245760)
    [libx264 @ 054c5c20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
    x264 [error]: malloc of size 152432416 failed
    Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_f32le (native) -> aac (native))
    Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

there is a strange message.
'malloc of size 152432416 failed'
I think this is memory problem but I have no idea to solve this problem.

This is avs file

```
    PluginPath = "D:\Application\Frame_Doubling_Set_Drag_And_Drop\ffmpeg-Convert-TrueMotion-x86_Newer_Svpflow\_exe\"

    LoadPlugin(PluginPath + "ffms2.dll")
    LoadPlugin(PluginPath + "svpflow1.dll")
    LoadPlugin(PluginPath + "svpflow2.dll")
    LoadPlugin(PluginPath + "mvtools2.dll")

    Video=FFVideoSource("a.mp4", threads=8) 
    Audio=FFAudioSource("a.mp4")
    Audiodub(Video, Audio)

    Import(PluginPath + "InterFrame2.avsi")

    InterFrame(GPU=true, Preset="Medium", FrameDouble=true, NewNum=60000, NewDen=1000, Cores=8)
```

and this is batch file

```
    @echo off

    CD /D "%~dp1"
    cls

    set DestPath=%~dp1

    set Src0=%~nx1
    set Src1=%~n1

    set DestExt=.mp4

    set Dest0=%DestPath%\%Src1%-Cnv%DestExt%
    set Dest1=%DestPath%\%Src1%-Cnv-New%DestExt%

    set exe=%~dp0_exe\ffmpeg.exe
    set Opt1=-i
    set Opt2=-c:v libx264 -b:v 200000k -minrate 10k -maxrate 200000k -profile:v high -level 4.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p
    set Opt3=-c:a aac -ab 192k
    set Opt4=-f mp4

    If Not Exist "%Src0%" (echo. && echo  [ %Src0% ] Not Found. && echo. && pause && Goto End)

    If Exist "%Dest0%" set Dest0=%Dest1%

    "%exe%" %Opt1% "%Src0%" %Opt2% %Opt3% %Opt4% "%Dest0%"

    :End
    If Not Exist "%Dest0%" (echo. && pause)
    rem pause
    pause
```

What's my problem?

Comment: As the msg says, the encoder requested some amount of memory and the request failed. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have 16mb ram and i7-4790k